# Merging a label over an image, and saving as a new image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm looking for a way to allow the user of my iPhone app to place labels on top of an image, and save the final result into a new image.

I've tried looking around, but so far I'm not 100% sure how should I start implementing this feature, or if this is the right approach to do something like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following snippet once ur code detects that User has entered the desired caption for an image:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = ( AppDelegate * ) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(appDelegate.window.bounds.size);
[appDelegate.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
// Save the data object to the the file.
```

Comment: So just to allow the user to create labels on top of the image, then execute the provided example?

Comment: Yes. This is one of the approaches. There could be others too. If I get time will try to provide other approach too. Till then I think this should work for you.